# Cant figure out this formula (Nesting IF/AND)

Tags: microsoft-excel

This statement should result in "T" as the cells would be true for the second IF(AND statement.

See screenshots below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Excel does not accept:

```
55<=D10<57
```

You need to split it in the AND:

```
AND(55<= D10,D10<57,...
```